# How would you reshape an array, iterate over all rows of a column, and assign the reshaped arrays to a new column? - Python/Pandas/Numpy

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, numpy

There are multiple ways of iterating over rows and applying a function. However, I couldn't apply that to my specific case. Here is a simple table explaining the problem:

```
    'Label'                    'Dimension'          'what I want'        
[12 323 345 235]                  (4,)                  (4,1)
[55 22 141 124 124]               (5,)                  (5,1)
[77 12 11]                        (3,)                  (3,1)
```

If I were to achieve this using 1 array, here is what it would look like:

```
label_ex = np.array([12,13,14,15])
label_ex.shape >> (4, )
label_ex = label_ex.reshape(len(label_ex), 1)
label_ex.shape >> (4, 1)
```

Here is what I tried:

```
for index, row in samp.iterrows():
    samp.loc[index, 'label'] = samp.loc[index, 'label'].reshape(len(samp.loc[index, 'label']), 1)
```

Somehow, this is converting all my arrays to lists and then shows the error

```
"AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'shape'"
```

I tried using the df.column.apply() method, but that also doesn't work (maybe I implemented it wrong).

How should I approach this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`df.apply()` will work.

```
df['New_Dimension'] = df['Label'].apply(lambda row : np.array(row).reshape(-1,1).shape)

>>>
    Label                        Dimension         New_Dimension      
[12, 323, 345, 235]                 (4,)                (4,1)
[55, 22, 141, 124, 124]             (5,)                (5,1)
[77, 12, 11]                        (3,)                (3,1)
```

Comment: Thank you, this solved my problem. However, I had to omit the .shape at the end, as it converts the array to a tuple. So this is that worked: `df['New_Dimension'] = df['Label'].apply(lambda row : np.array(row).reshape(-1,1))`

Comment: Are you referring to the arrays under the `Label` column? If so, they should have remained the same. Without `.shape`, you will get a reshaped array and not the dimensions as you specified in the question.

Here we are simply creating a new column by applying a function to it.

Comment: I actually wanted the reshaped arrays from the "Label" column. I wanted the output to be the same array but with the "New_Dimension" dimensions.